# Numpy boolean masking -- multidimension and floats

Tags: python, numpy

I have a huge 4 dimensional array, but for this example I will use a 3-dimenisonal array, `x`.

The array is of type float.

I'm trying to use boolean masking to locate specific numbers and then change those numbers to another number.

However, it seems I'm unable to locate some float numbers despite them being a 
element in my array 'x'

x is a 32,32,3 array

Here is how a portion of my `x` array  looks like :

```
>>> x

array([[[ -71.71074,  -74.05614,  -69.5538 ],
        [ -87.14036,  -89.44238,  -86.85358],
        [ -81.05044,  -88.24616,  -89.58144],
        ..., 
        [  26.94098,   -4.307  ,  -24.44078],
        [  21.60692,  -10.70848,  -30.00036],
        [  17.826  ,  -11.4736 ,  -28.89246]],

       [[-114.0993 , -115.29484, -111.36412],
        [-129.3446 , -134.45914, -130.4656 ],
        [-112.2169 , -127.1767 , -131.10234],
        ..., 
        [  -7.04254,  -47.13862,  -75.90018],
        [ -10.33038,  -51.55898,  -80.49918],
        [  -7.1568 ,  -47.38368,  -73.45104]],

       [[-104.72472, -110.64818, -109.2514 ],
        [-112.71662, -126.49748, -129.01922],
        [ -80.47348, -107.05546, -121.47586],
        ..., 
        [ -11.21066,  -49.95824,  -79.29398],
        [  -8.59094,  -49.54152,  -79.06528],
        [ -19.59134,  -60.55772,  -87.22356]],

       ..., 
       [[  81.44628,   44.0467 ,  -18.1421 ],
        [  76.41156,   29.2665 ,  -77.77894],
        [  74.07492,   38.1989 ,  -84.73544],
        ..., 
        [  35.75964,    9.99658,  -40.87088],
        [ -68.68902,  -92.7463 , -104.75116],
        [ -72.51674,  -90.86008,  -93.10554]],

       [[  52.9319 ,   12.62384,  -18.64896],
        [  47.53098,   -1.58318,  -70.6934 ],
        [  60.71512,   19.8131 ,  -82.16812],
        ..., 
        [  58.50748,   23.66242,  -18.25642],
        [ -28.58606,  -62.64844,  -78.71842],
        [ -42.9967 ,  -72.2858 ,  -79.60626]],

       [[  49.26526,   17.05222,    0.55436],
        [  41.40204,    3.34674,  -19.9712 ],
        [  52.13484,   16.24322,  -26.9406 ],
        ..., 
        [  89.22164,   58.30292,   26.16942],
        [  24.43504,   -7.61742,  -29.90624],
        [  -3.63908,  -33.8503 ,  -42.38186]]])
```

So I picked numbers within this array and see if I could locate them using boolean masking. However, only some numbers were located:

This located the element:

```
>>> x[x==60.71512]
array([ 60.71512])
```

However, this didn't locate the element

```
>>> x[x==-28.58606]
array([], dtype=float64)

#empty array result despite being an element within my array
```

I'm confused by this behavior.

My ultimate goal is to locate all 0 elements within my 4-dimensional arrays and 
convert them .1.

`y` is my 4-dimesional array (holding images)

I was assuming `y[y==0] = .1` would work, but now do the strange behavior above,
I'm not sure if the empty arrays I'm getting are due to the behavior above or due to there not actually being zeros in my array.

Also, since I"m dealing with floats, should it be `y[y==0.00]`?

Comment: Try `np.isclose()`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any `0` elements in this `array`... Do you mean exactly `0` as in `0.00000....` or `0 <= e < 1`?

Comment: first use `np.set_printoptions(17)` to see all the decimals... an use `np.isclose` as already mentionned

Comment: @B.M.  Yeah, np.isclose fixes the float problem. Thank you

Comment: @Divakar  Yeah, np.isclose fixes the float problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean literally elements of *exactly* value `0`, then yes, you can do what you suggested in the question. Note that when testing these operations for `multi-dimensional` `arrays`, it can sometimes help to simplify by working with `1d` `arrays`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0], dtype="float32")
>>> a[a==0] = 1
>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  4.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  7.,  1.], dtype=float32)
```

---

As first mentioned by [`@Divikar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316515/numpy-boolean-masking-multidimension-and-floats/47316627#comment81583922_47316515), you can use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to get rid of the errors caused by the `floats`.

Comment: Yeah, I meant exactly zero (to avoid zero division problems). Thank you.

Comment: Hi Joe, sorry about that. Jjust include Divakar's portion as well as he answered the other part of my question.